How do I compare a string with an array of strings by length?
/**
 * @param {string} str1 - the first string to compare
 * @param {string} str2 - the second string to compare
 * @returns {number} the absolute difference in length between `str1` and `str2`
 */
const getDistanceByLength = (str1, str2) => {
  return Math.abs(str1.length-str2.length);
};

/**
 * @param {string} word - the original string
 * @param {string[]} words - an array of strings
 * @param {(str1: string, str2: string) => number} - a function that
 *  takes two strings and returns a number representing the distance between them
 * @param {number} threshold - the maximum distance that is still considered "close"
 * @returns {string} the string in `words` with the minimum distance to `word`
 *  as calculated by `distanceFn`, unless that distance is strictly greater than
 *  the `threshold`, in which case the original `word` is returned.
 */
const getClosestWord = (word, words, getDistanceByLength, threshold) => {
  for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    if(getDistanceByLength(word,words[i]) <= threshold){
      return words[i];
    }
  }
  return word;

};

The problem I am having is I just cannot figure out the logic necessary in getClosestWord() to loop through the array and come out with the shortest distance (from getDistanceByLength). It also returns the first word if the distance is larger than a threshold. Right now, it stops looping as soon as it hits a word that passes the criteria, instead of going through the whole array, and choosing the words[i] that has the shortest distance.
The word is just a random word passed in the function. The array of words I am using:
words: ["bed", "bank", "fence", "bridges"] 
If any of this is condescending please let me know, or if you all need any more information.

using return inside your loop will stop it. You'll need to check all your words, so you can't return within your loop. Instead of returning inside your loop, update a variable that keeps track of the word with the currently seen shortest distance that's less than your threshold, then return that at the end

What would the logic look like to constantly update a variable? Should I nest another loop? I just cant grasp what would be the best way to implement that.

To find the word with the shortest distance in your array that's less than the threshold, you need to:

Check all words in your array (that means you can't return within your loop as that will terminate it early)
Confirm that the distance of the current word is less than the threshold distance
Confirm that the distance of the current word is less than the distance of the previously seen closest word.

To remove the return in the middle of your loop, you should keep track of what the closest word is that you've seen so far. Below I'm storing this word in a variable called closestWord so that you can return it after your loop has finished (after your loop has finished, you've looked at all words, so you can safely say that the closest word is in closestWord). The other thing you can store (but not mandatory to do), is the calculated distance of the closestWord. Below I'm storing that in closestDist. This allows you to confirm that the distance calculated for the current word is smaller than (or equal to if you want to grab the last closest distance word seen) the closest word distance seen so far. We technically could remove the closestDist as it can be calculated by calling getDistanceByLength and passing in closestWord and word, but this allows us to initialise it to Infinity, making the comparison logic easier within the loop as you don't need to special-case the first time you come across a word that's less than the threshold to update closestWord:


const getDistanceByLength = (str1, str2) => Math.abs(str1.length - str2.length);

const getClosestWord = (word, words, distanceFn, threshold) => {
  let closestWord = word;
  let closestDist = Infinity;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const currDist = distanceFn(word, words[i]);
    // If the current word's distance is less than the threshold
    // and its distance is less than the distance for the closest word seen so far
    if (currDist <= threshold && currDist <= closestDist) {
      closestWord = words[i];
      closestDist = currDist;
    }
  }
  return closestWord;
};

console.log(getClosestWord(
  "mouse", ["fish", "cat", "dog", "bird", "ant", "ox", "squid"],
  getDistanceByLength,
  4
));




This works great thank you! For some reason, though, when I pass in a six-character string and do not have a six-character string in the array, it defaults to the next higher string. (i.e. I pass through rivers, but only have a fence and bridges within my array. It seems to always default to bridges.) Do you know why? Is it just the order it's getting passed in?

@antjuh Hi, it will pick the last closest string in the array, so yes, it's based on order. Since the distance between fence and bridges is both 1 (for the word rivers), but bridges is last, it picks that. If you want it to be the first closest string, then you can change currDist <= closestDist to be currDist < closestDist
